# Push Metadata into Datalayer

Tags: javascript, metadata, google-tag-manager

We do have those metadata:

```
<meta property="article:tag" content="bread">
<meta property="article:tag" content="butter">
<meta property="article:tag" content="cheese">
<meta property="article:section" content="food">
```

We want to push all `article:tag` seperate into the datalayer.

The Result should be something like this:

```
tag: bread
tag: butter
tag: cheese
```

the only solution i have found gives me:

```
tag: bread, butter, cheese
```

In the end I want to evaluate which Tag has the most pageviews in Analytics.

Comment: Do you have a defined list of what tags exist? Are you wanting them separated in a specific order and want to send them as custom dimensions to GA?

Comment: Can we assume that not all these tags appear at once per article (else all tags would have the same number of pageviews)? Are these mutually exclusive, or will some articles have multiple tags?

Comment: there is no defined List, the editors use tags however they want :( And yes, on some articles appearing 5 Tags, on some others just one - some articles have multiple tags. I want to sepperate them, for 2 occasions - first fire a trigger on specific tag, second creatu a custom dimension to monitor the performance

Comment: Can you post your solution so far? What have you used to get `tag: bread, butter, cheese`